# Current trade profit/loss sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying my hand at a couple of tester database interview questions; coming from a client side background, I'm doing a few to get up to scratch, and I'm currently struggling.

I have a portfolio table with 'TradeID', 'Ticker', 'Price', and 'Volume'. Currently 3 rows in the table, 2 buys of 10,000 and 1 sell of 10,000, all of the same company. I basically need to work out the daily portfolio value given a price. So if the current price is 1.00, the value total would be 10,000.

I've tried every subquery possible, but cannot for the life of me get it working, I end up with a aggregate or group by error, any help would be appreciated. Apologies if I've missed anything.

Edit: I'm trying to create a query like this:

```
select
 sum
((sum(trade.volume) * 1.0) -
  (sum(trade.volume * trade.price)))

from trade
```

Edit2: test data I currently have & making example easier:

1.0 is the price at close.
I have 3 trades; trade.volume for the three would be +10,000, +10,000, -10,000 - all the same company
trade.price : 1.1  - is the price the stock was bought at

so with sum((trade.volume) *1) I'm trying to get 10,000 as the current value from open volumes
 (sum(trade.volume * trade.price)) would be 11,000 as purchase price

Comment: a SUM() and a case statement to determine which rows are buys versus sells are sufficient

Comment: Hi Mitch, I've not taken the case route; cheers, I'll take a look.

Comment: Can you post some sample data...

Answer (score 0):

If the sell is negative then

```
Select ticket, sum(volume*trade) from table group by ticket
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you have:

```
CREATE TABLE Portfolio (
    TradeID int,
    Ticker varchar(10),    -- the company identifer
    Price money,
    Volume int,    -- probably not actually an int
)
```

with data:

```
INSERT Portfolio VALUES ( 1, 'ACME', 1.1, 10000) -- a buy
INSERT Portfolio VALUES ( 2, 'ACME', 1.1, 10000) -- a buy
INSERT Portfolio VALUES ( 3, 'ACME', 1.1, -10000) -- a sell
```

Given

> I basically need to work out the daily portfolio value given a price. So if the current price is 1.00, the value total would be 10,000.

I *think* you want the current net `Volume`, multiplied by today's price:

```
DECLARE @priceNow money
SET @priceNow = 1.0

DECLARE @currentValue money
SELECT @currentValue = @priceNow * SUM(Volume) FROM Portfolio WHERE Ticker = 'ACME'
```

Note that the *transaction price* is irrelevant to knowing the currently-owned *value*.